# Transport Level Error on Ubuntu with the SQL Server extension in VS Code (and Azure Data Studio)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-code

When trying to execute a long query I'm getting some sort of timeout apparently? I'm not sure about what's happening. The error message I receive is the following:

> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught).

The strange thing is that I have no problem when trying to run a simpler version of the query, it works fine. Also, another thing I noticed is that when running the same long query on Windows through SQL Server Management Studio does actually work, so maybe there are some hidden configurations on Linux or inside VS Code that are different from SQL Server?

I've also been having the same issue when using `Azure Data Studio`, which seems to use the same VS Code core.

I've tried to add the below configurations after finding them in a post, but they don't seem to change anything (I don't know if they are legit VS Code configurations actually):

```
"Trusted_Connection": false,
"Pooling": false
```

By the way, I've also posted [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-mssql/issues/1241) on Github, but haven't yet been answered.

Comment: Do you select any NVARCHAR(MAX)/VARBINARY/XML column?

Comment: No, not at all.